# add jquery to wordpress individual page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to implement some jquery code in wwordpress page for client. The code works perfectly in the html file but not in wordpress page. Please tell me if I could add that code in the same file and need not to be add any code in a separate file. The code is:

`

```
<p><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><br />
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var limit = 3;
     $('input').on('change', function() {
     if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
    }
  });
  </script></p>
```

`

Comment: Any error message? You don't have to add a `p` or `br` tag, cause the `script` tags are not rendered to the page.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745853/having-trouble-understanding-how-to-properly-enqueue-jquery-in-wordpress/27746044#27746044

To summarise, use the correct WordPress functions to load jQuery. Then alter your JS to accommodate WP loading jQuery in noConflict mode.

Answer (score 2):

Do not add

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Wordpress already has it included. And adding it twice cause it to be not working right.

Comment: This depends on the theme, which is used! Some themes don't need jquery and don`t include the shipped one.

Comment: do you have your wordpress page on a local machine or on a server?

Comment: One more thing I must tell you is that I am adding the code in the HTML Section of the page

Comment: this wordpress page is not in my local machine

Comment: if you have firebug, if not download it. Pres F12, console tab and tell me the error.. In Firefox

Comment: yes it is under the HTML code.....have a look at this image http://prntscr.com/5ta2yx

Comment: can you give us HTML code when you inspect it? or just give me the url to the wordpress site

Comment: can't provide the url since you will need to add username and password to access that page

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var limit = 3;
     jQuery('input').on('change', function() {
     if(jQuery(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
         this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

Change $ with jQuery

Comment: into script add text/javascript -- > <script type="text/javascript">